# AutoCAD .SendStringToExicute ATTEDIT not selecting selected object

Tags: c#, autocad, autodesk

Trying to run ATTEDIT from the Command line after double clicking and have it select the previously selected item. I've intercepted the double click event and can run ATTEDIT, but when I try to pass the position through to the "ATTEDIT Select a block:" it doesn't do anything. But will work when I click on the block again. I thought it was just because I had the units in decimal units rather than architectural. But that doesn't work as well. Here is what I have:

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class DoubleClickProcess
{
// This function gets called when a block reference is double clicked on. It then checks to see if the block reference
// that was double clicked on was double clicked
[CommandMethod("DOUBLECLICK", CommandFlags.UsePickSet)]
public void ContinueDoubleClick()
{
  Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
  Database database = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
  Editor ed = doc.Editor;

  // Get the PickFirst selection set
  PromptSelectionResult acSSPrompt;
  acSSPrompt = ed.SelectImplied();

  SelectionSet selRes;

  // If the prompt status is OK, objects were selected before
  // the command was started
  if (acSSPrompt.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
  {
    selRes = acSSPrompt.Value;

    Transaction tr = doc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();
    using (tr)
    {
      // Go through all of the objects that were selected...
      ObjectId[] objIds = selRes.GetObjectIds();
      foreach (ObjectId objId in objIds)
      {
        Entity theEnt = (Entity)tr.GetObject(objId, OpenMode.ForRead);

        // They must be block references...
        if (theEnt.GetType().Name.ToUpper() == "BLOCKREFERENCE")
        {
          BlockReference bRef = theEnt as BlockReference;

          BlockTableRecord btr = null;
          btr = tr.GetObject(bRef.DynamicBlockTableRecord, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;

          if (bRef != null)
          {
            // If it is a specific block then we are interested in it
            if (btr.Name.ToString().ToUpper() == "specific")
            {
              doc.SendStringToExecute("SomeCommand ", true, false, true);
            }
            else
            {
              // It's not one we're interested in so do what double clicking would normally do
              String objPx = Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Converter.DistanceToString(bRef.Position.X);
              objPx = objPx.Replace(" ", "-");
              String objPy = Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Converter.DistanceToString(bRef.Position.Y);
              objPy = objPy.Replace(" ", "-");
              String objP =   objPx +","+ objPy;
              doc.SendStringToExecute("ATTEDIT "+ objP + " ", true, false, true);
            }
          }
        }
        theEnt.Dispose();
      }
      tr.Commit();
    }
  }

  // Clear the PickFirst selection set
  ObjectId[] idarrayEmpty = new ObjectId[0];
  ed.SetImpliedSelection(idarrayEmpty);
  }
 }
}
```

Typing in the architectual position of the mouse works(101'-6-7/8",89'-5-1/2"), but if you type the actual position of the block it doesn't select the block attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should work with SetImpliedSelection:

```
SelectionSet selset = SelectionSet.FromObjectIds(new ObjectId[] { bRef.ObjectId });
ed.SetImpliedSelection(selset);
doc.SendStringToExecute("ATTEDIT ", true, false, true);
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work. The selset value shows as:{(((8796087858048),Unavailable,0,))} but I think it should be something like: {(((8796087858048),PickPoint,1,))}. Would you know how to get the PickPoint and the 1 in there?

Comment: Any other suggestions?